# SQL Find a movie that has been shown at least 2 times

Tags: sql

Okay, while i was studying i came onto a bump.

I have a database containing

```
City(Name,State,Population)

Theatre(Theatre_id,name,City_Name)

ScreeningRoom(ScreeningRoom_Number,theatre_tid,Capacity)

Movie(Movie_id,title,lenght)

Screening(Screening_id,Movie_fid,SreeningR_number,viewers)
```

I need to find all the movies that had been Screened at least 2 times in each Screening room.
I managed to find a solution for all the movies that had been screened in each screening room and my code goes like this

```
select * from movie
where not exists
    (
    select * from ScreeningRoom 
    where not exists(
        select * from Screening
        where movies.movie_id=screeing.Movie_fid
        and ScreeningRoom.ScreeningRoom_Number=Screening.Screening_id
    )
    )
group by movie.title
```

But i don't know how to implement the at least 2 times part...Please help

Comment: Please, do not tag multiple RDBMS, are you sure you want an answer for MySQL and SQL Server too?. Please tag your question only with the relevant tags.

Comment: Not sure what database you're using and how the data looks like but you could probably use a window function to `count(*) over(partition by SreeningR_number)` and filter the result in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I have added a having clause to the statement.

```
select * from movie
where not exists
    (
    select * from ScreeningRoom 
    where not exists(
        select * from Screening
        where movies.movie_id=screeing.Movie_fid
        and ScreeningRoom.ScreeningRoom_Number=Screening.Screening_id
        having count(Screening.Screening_id) >1
    )
    )
group by movie.title
```

Answer (score 0):

you are almost close to the answer. You need group by and having constraint in your exists part.

And It seems that you need to use Exists rather then not exists

```
select * from movie
where exists
    (
    select 1 from ScreeningRoom 
    where exists(
        select 1 from Screening
        where movies.movie_id=screeing.Movie_fid
          and ScreeningRoom.ScreeningRoom_Number=Screening.Screening_id
        group by Movie_Fid
        having count(*) >= 2 
         )
    )
group by movie.title
```